# How do I package/access public resources in a GWT module?

Tags: gwt

I am trying to package a few custom GWT widgets I have developed into a separate GWT module so that they could be reused in other projects. My problem is figuring out where in the created JAR file should public resources like images and stylesheets be placed and what path do I then use to access them?

I have a JAR structure that looks like this

com

--- companyname

------ gwt                                 !Widgets.gwt.xml file

--------- client                           !Java classes

META-INF

public

--- image

--- stylesheet

Widgets.gwt.xml needs to access a stylesheet in the public folder so I include the line  and the Java classes need to access the images so I am using 'images/Calender.png' for that but when I run the application I get [WARN] 404 - GET messages and the resources aren't loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GWT's [ClientBundle](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) functionality to access resources in your module. This will let you keep them in your `src` directories and prevent you from having to make any assumptions about how consumers of the module deploy their applications.

Comment: And don't forget to call ensureInjected() in every project that uses your packaged gwt module.

Answer (score 0):

Typically jars containing widgets go in your war/WEB-INF/lib directory.  Resources such as stylesheets often go in war/.  There are other ways, such as Client Bundles, as well, and you should consult the GWT docs about those.